# How to ignore the columns as part of columnstore index that cannot be participated because of data type issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2012, clustered-index

I have an existing table which has more than 100 columns in it. Now I am trying to create a clustered columnstore index on the same table but it throws me an error as some of the columns do not meet the data types criteria due to restrictions. Is there a way to ignore the columns that do not meet the Clustered ColumnStore Index requirements. Thank you.

```
SQL for creating CCSI :-



CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX CCSI 
ON [Dbname].[dbo].[testtable] 
WITH ( DROP_EXISTING = OFF );

Error :-

The statement failed. Column 'Column1' has a data type that cannot participate in a columnstore index. Omit column 'Column1'.
```

Comment: Whenever you create the columnstore index, you MUST NOT include any column which has datatype that is not supported by columnstore index - https://raresql.com/tag/create-index-statement-failed-column-has-a-data-type-that-cannot-participate-in-a-columnstore-index-omit-column/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot ignore columns while using Clustered ColumnStore Index. For selected columns you must go for Non Clustered ColumnStore Index as below:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX CCSI 
ON [Dbname].[dbo].[testtable] (Col1, Col2...required columns)
WITH ( DROP_EXISTING = OFF );
```

Comment: I am iterating through a list of tables and want to write my solution generic instead of hard coding the columns. Each table has its own columns.

Comment: You might require to iterate all the column names using sys.columns for that table and generate that as there is no way to exclude columns in clustered columnstore index